# Using DI container in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

We've been using Simple Injector with good success, in a fairly substantial application. We've been using constructor injection for all of our production classes, and configuring Simple Injector to populate everything, and everything's peachy.

We've not, though, used Simple Injector to manage the dependency trees for our unit tests. Instead, we've been new'ing up everything manually.

I just spent a couple of days working through a major refactoring, and nearly all of my time was in fixing these manually-constructed dependency trees in our unit tests.

This has me wondering - does anyone have any patterns they use to configure the dependency trees they use in unit tests?  For us, at least, in our tests our dependency trees tend to be fairly simple, but there are a lot of them.

Anyone have a method they use to manage these?

Comment: Not sure what pattern do you seek. Why not just make your containers in test initialization (constructor for xunit, e.g.)? The pattern is simple -- composition.

Comment: If you're really interested in unit test patterns, you should read [xUnit Test Patterns](https://www.amazon.co.uk/xUnit-Test-Patterns-Refactoring-Code-ebook/dp/B004X1D36K/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1).

Comment: And read "Test Driven Development: By Example"

Answer (score 18):

For true unit tests (i.e. those which only test one class, and mock all of its dependencies), it doesn't make any sense to use a DI framework. In these tests:

- if you find that you have a lot of repetitive code for `new`ing up an instance of your class with all the mocks you've created, one useful strategy is to create all of your mocks and create the instance for the subject-under-test in your Setup method (these can all be private instance fields), and then each individual test's "arrange" area just has to call the appropriate `Setup()` code on the methods it needs to mock. This way, you end up with only one `new PersonController(...)` statement per test class.
- if you're needing to create a lot of domain/data objects, it's useful to create Builder objects that start with sane values for testing. So instead of invoking a huge constructor all over your code, with a bunch of fake values, you're mostly just calling, e.g., `var person = new PersonBuilder().Build()`, possibly with just a few chained method calls for pieces of data that you specifically care about in that test. You may also be interested in [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture), but I've never used it so I can't vouch for it.

If you're writing *integration* tests, where you need to test the interaction between several parts of the system, but you still need to be able to mock specific pieces, consider creating Builder classes for your services, so you can say, e.g. `var personController = new PersonControllerBuilder.WithRealDatabase(connection).WithAuthorization(new AllowAllAuthorizationService()).Build()`.

If you're writing end-to-end, or "scenario" tests, where you need to test the whole system, then it makes sense to set up your DI framework, leveraging the same configuration code that your real product uses. You can alter the configuration slightly to give yourself better programmatic control over things like which user is logged in and such. You can still leverage the other builder classes you've created for constructing data, too.

```
var user = new PersonBuilder().Build();
using(Login.As(user))
{
     var controller = Container.Get<PersonController>();
     var result = controller.GetCurrentUser();
     Assert.AreEqual(result.Username, user.Username)
}
```

Comment: I believe that [Object Mother](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Helper.html) is the name of the builder pattern in case of unit tests.  Nice answer btw. +1

Comment: Opposite answer at: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140992/is-dependency-injection-essential-for-unit-testing

Comment: @sotn: That doesn't appear to be the same question, and I don't see any answers there that appear to contradict this. Can you link directly to the answer you're talking about, and explain how it's "opposite" to this?

Comment: AutoFixture and its extensions are great by the way. I highly recommend it. I am using it alongside moq, it allows you to return mock objects with all their dependencies mocked as well.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş: Thanks for sharing. In the years since I posted this answer, I have had the chance to use AutoFixture, and I agree. I couple it with the [Automoq extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq/) and freeze mock objects in my setup method. And by adding some Customizations, I avoid the need for Builder/Factory objects for my models. I don't have to clutter my code with meaningless strings and numbers. It's great.

Comment: "For true unit tests" - true unit tests are the one that use Test Driven Development (with BDD style) and mocks are discouraged there. Mocks should be only on the module's edges, not inside. And class is not a module. If you mock all dependencies of a class, refactoring will be impossible without breaking tests.

Comment: @andrew.fox: That's an interesting perspective. I've found it advantageous to use automated tests at a variety of levels, even when practicing BDD. From [the Wikipedia article on Unit Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing): "In object-oriented programming, a unit is often an entire interface, such as a class, or an individual method... Substitutes such as method stubs, mock objects, fakes, and test harnesses can be used to assist testing a module in isolation." For a class-sized unit, its dependencies _are_ its edges.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - What you wrote is so called "London school" that came later. It has some advantages (easy to start) and many disadvantages (hard to maintain in the long run). Please check "TDD, Where Did It All Go Wrong (Ian Cooper)" ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM ) or Robert C. Martin's https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html .

Comment: @andrew.fox: Thanks for the article and video, and for giving me the vocabulary "London school of unit testing" which led to [this chapter](https://freecontent.manning.com/what-is-a-unit-test-part-2-classical-vs-london-schools/), which was more useful to understand where you're coming from. I find that I've naturally switched between London school and classical depending on the type of system I'm testing. I also often skip writing unit tests at all for functionality that is so straightforward that the unit test would just be a mirror of the code itself.

Answer (score 12):

Refrain from using your DI container within your unit tests. In unit tests, you try to test one class or module in isolation, and there is little use for a DI container in that area.

Things are different with integration testing, since you want to test how the components in your system integrate and work together. In that case you often use your production DI configuration and swap out some of your services for fake services (e.g. a `EmailService`) but stick as close to the real thing as you can. In this case you would typically use your Container to resolve the whole object graph.

The desire to use a DI container in the unit tests as well, often stems from ineffective patterns. For instance, in case you try to create the class under test with all its dependencies in each test, you get lots of duplicated initialization code, and a little change in your class under test can in that case ripple through the system and require you to change dozens of unit tests. This obviously causes maintainability problems.

One pattern that helped me out here a lot in the past is the use of a simple SUT-specific factory method. This method centralizes the creation of the class under test and minimizes the amount of changes that need to be made when the dependencies of the class under test change. This is how such factory method could look like:

```
private ClassUnderTest CreateClassUnderTest(
    ILogger logger = null,
    IMailSender mailSender = null,
    IEventPublisher publisher = null)
{
    return new ClassUnderTest(
        logger ?? new FakeLogger(),
        mailSender ?? new FakeMailer(),
        publisher ?? new FakePublisher());
}
```

The factory method's arguments duplicate the class's constructor arguments, but makes them all optional. For any particular dependency that is not supplied by the caller, a new default fake implementation will be injected.

This typically works very well, because in most tests you are just interested in one or two dependencies. The other dependencies might be required for the class to function, but might not be interesting for that specific test. The factory method, therefore, allows you to only supply the dependencies that are interesting for the test at hand, while removing the noise of unused dependencies from the test method. As an example using the factory method, here's a test method:

```
public void Doing_something_will_always_log_a_message()
{
    // Arrange
    var logger = new ListLogger();

    ClassUnderTest sut = CreateClassUnderTest(logger: logger);

    // Act
    sut.DoSomething();
    
    // Arrange
    Assert.IsTrue(logger.Count > 0);    
}
```

If you are interested in learning how to write Readable, Trustworthy and Maintainable ([RTM](https://osherove.com/blog/2009/12/31/rtm-ready-tests.html)) tests, Roy Osherove's book [The Art of Unit Testing (second edition)](https://www.manning.com/osherove2) is an excellent read. This has helped me tremendously in my understanding of writing great unit tests. If you’re interested in a deep-dive into Dependency Injection and its related patterns, consider reading [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (which I co-authored).

Comment: What you propose is "London school of unit testing", i.e. using mocks excessively. It leads to fragile tests, that fail to compile whenever you change any internals or refactors. 
To the OP, I suggest reading about "Chicago school of TDD" where you test behaviors (hence BDD practice was invented to emphasize the need of user flows in tests). BDD was later stolen by Gerkin, but it's not the same thing.