# Should I use a dependency injection container in Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a class that is created, during runtime, through JSON deserialization:

```
public class Server
    {
        protected IDataRepository DataRepository;
        public string Name { get; }

        protected Server(string Name, IDataRepository DataRepository)
        {
            this.Name = HostName;
            this.DataRepository= DataRepository;
        }
    }
```

The deserialization is done in a specific class:

```
public class SettingsServersRepository : IServersRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Server> Servers {get;}

        public SettingsServersRepository(string jsonSettings)
        {
            Servers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Server>>(jsonSettings);
        }
    }
```

During the deserialization process, a `IDataRepository` is injected into the `Server` using constructor injection.

It works fine at runtime.

However, when I want to unit-test the class:

```
public void CreateFromBasicJSON()
        {
            //Arrange
            string testJSON = "[{'Name': 'foo'},{'Name': 'bar'}]";
            //Act
            IServersRepository serverRepoFromJson = new SettingsServersRepository(testJSON);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(serverRepoFromJson.Servers.ElementAt(0).Name == 
                "foo");
        }
```

The dependency is missing, and an `NullReferenceError` is thrown in the `Server` constructor.

My first thought is to use a dependency injection container in the unit-test to make sure the dependency is injected.

It does not feel like `the right thing to do™` but short of building a custom JsonConverter only for that purpose, and carrying the `IServersRepository` down the stack, I don't have a better idea.

**The question:**

Is it OK to use a dependency injection container in a unit test? If not, how can I improve?

Comment: [This answer *may* be relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595102/106159)