# TestHost and DependencyInjection on Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, dependency-injection, integration

So i'm trying to find out how to implement dependency injection on the project for testing.

Currently I'm using the `TestHost` but the problem is I don't really understand how `TestHost` should help me with DI on the service level because all examples I was looking at ([here](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/08/21/testing-an-asp-net-core-application-using-testserver), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/test-aspnet-core-services-web-apps), [here](https://andrewlock.net/configuring-environment-specific-services-in-asp-net-core/) and [here](https://andrewlock.net/configuring-environment-specific-services-in-asp-net-core-part-2/)) didn't tell me something more clear than just some examples of code for Integration Testing on Controller level while I'm looking for services and possibility to inject all dependencies without any problems.

I've created the new Environment for Test project and I tried to implement DI via `TestHost` on the test method just like in examples:

```
var someClass = new SomeClassService(IRepository, IRepository, IRepository);
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseEnvironment("Testing")
    .UseStartup<TestStartup>();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595171/264697

Comment: Thanks, will check for it.