# ServiceCollection does not contain a definition from "AddLogging"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm currently trying to create a Logger so I can inject it in Unit Tests. I'm following  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425633/1057052, and it used to work! I then moved the project and reestablished the dependencies, and now I'm getting

> 'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddLogging' and
>   no accessible extension method 'AddLogging' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'ServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

There must be something silly I'm missing. Currently under ASP.NET Core 2.2, and I believe I have assigned the correct dependencies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.loggingservicecollectionextensions.addlogging?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I've been reinstalling for the past hour our so! Can't nail what the problem is

Here's the code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Planificacion.UnitTest.Config
{
    public class LoggerTestConfig
    {
        private LoggerTestConfig()
        {

        }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425633/1057052
        public static ILogger<T> GetLoggerConfig<T>() where T : class
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var factory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

            return factory.CreateLogger<T>();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should [not use a DI Container when writing unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594803/using-di-container-in-unit-tests).

Comment: @Steven: Thanks! I wasn't. I was trying to create the ILogger concrete implementation so I could inject it in the dependencies that needed it.

Comment: The ServiceCollection *is* a container. You should create the class under tedt by hand by injecting a fake logger manually. Not by a container.

Comment: @Steven: Does that mean that I'm doing integration tests instead of true unit tests?

Comment: That is a question I can't answer. An integration test is meant to test a larger part of the application, typically in relation with some of its external components, while a unit test is meant to test an isolated 'unit' (or use case). I don't know which you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Steven I was trying to achieve a Unit Test mocking as little as possible. But I guess that's where Integration Tests fall into.

Comment: Ok, before Stack Overflow complaints. I've found my answer in [here ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65477/why-is-it-important-that-a-unit-test-not-test-dependencies?rq=1)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The image highlights that the dependency injection dll is referenced, but desired  [LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.loggingservicecollectionextensions.addlogging?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as shown in the links provided, indicates

```
Namespace:    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Assembly:    Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll <----NOTE THIS
```

Which is not referenced as shown in the image.

Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll` assembly stated above.

Comment: ! I have learned something super important today! That was it!

Comment: I have the nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, I declare a using in the file, but still it refuses to compile in .Net Core 2.1. I will try with .Net Core 2.2 SDK

Comment: @vilmir maybe this is three years too late but a common mistake is putting AddLogging against the wrong type. For example <some variable derived from IConfigurationBuilder>.AddLogging() would not compile. <some variable derived from IServiceCollection>.AddLogging() would compile.

Answer (score 0):

If your all configs are correctly but can't use useAutoMapper or smth, update version.