# ASP.NET Core - What challenges or issues may arise from using [FromServices] attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a Controller in ASP Core MVC. I'm trying to trim down the dependency injected services in the constructor so I can start building unit tests more easily. However, I have some services being injected that are only used in one or two controller actions. For example, I inject `ILocationService` because in a couple of my actions, I need to lookup a country `Id` number and get a ISO Alpha-2 country code using a database (eg mapping ID number 1 to "CA", mapping 2 to "US", etc.)

Asp Core supports the `[FromServices]` attribute, so I have the option to inject `ILocationService` directly into two of my actions instead of injecting them in the controller constructor. The advantage for this is I don't need to always mock/inject `ILocationService` into my controller from every unit test and its more clear when writing unit tests which services each function depends on.

The obvious disadvantage is now its not completely obvious and clear what services my controller depends on since they are not all grouped in the constructor.

Are there any other specific challenges, issues, or points of confusion that may arise from using the `[FromServices]` attribute?

Comment: This question, at its core, asks whether using Method Injection is a bad practice or not, which is an opinionated question so this will be closed as such. At least Microsoft thinks it can be needed for some reasons, otherwise that attribute wouldn't exist.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few unfortunate downsides to this type of [method injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) that you should consider:

- Such `[FromServices]` attribute can be easily forgotten, and you will only find out when the action is invoked (instead of finding out at application start-up -or during a unit test- where you can verify the application's configuration)
- The need for moving away from [constructor injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/) for performance reasons is an indication that injected components are too heavy to create, while [injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), and component creation should, therefore, be very lightweight.
- The need for moving away from constructor injection to prevent constructors from becoming too large is an indication that your classes have too many dependencies and are becoming too complex. In other words, having many dependencies is an indication that the class violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). The fact that your controller actions can easily be split over different classes is proof that such controller is not very cohesive and, therefore, an indication of a SRP violation.

So instead of hiding the root problem with the use of method injection, I advise the use of constructor injection as sole injection pattern here and make your controllers smaller. This might mean, however, that your routing scheme becomes different from your class structure, but this is perfectly fine, and completely supported by ASP.NET Core.

From a testability perspective, btw, it shouldn’t really matter if there sometimes is a dependency that isn’t needed. There are [effective test patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595171/264697) that fix this problem.

Comment: As I read this, I could see how the routing scheme will become different from class structure. Can you provide link to information demonstrating an alternate scheme as you are envisioning? I'm new to asp.net and the few routes I have perfectly mimic the Controller class structure.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, I will ask a few questions:
1. Why do I have to remember all the stuffs (dependencies) when I only need to care at specific action?
2. My controller class is designed to have N actions (URL route). Why do I have to split my controller to multiple classes (and add extra works for configuring routes) just because its constructor has many dependencies instead of keeping these actions thin and use method injection? 
3. On new action, why do I have to update constructor and also unit tests for this updating?
I think both way have their own advantages/disadvantages.