# When will a singleton/scoped/transient service instantiate?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Lets say I have 3 services each with different lifetimes.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService2, Service2>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IService3, Service3>();
```

Then, I have 3 controllers each injected with their respective service.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/controller1")]
public class Controller1 : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IService1 _service1;
    public Controller1(IService1 service1)
    {
        this._service1 = service1;
    }

    [HttpPost("request-1")]
    public IActionResult Request1()
    {
        // Do something with service 1
    }
}
// Repeat for the other 2 controller each injected with different service
```

When will each service be instantiated?

In my understanding, all services will only be instantiated when they are requested ***despite*** having different lifetime. Which means if I call `request-1`, only `Service1` will be instantiated. Only when I call `request-2`, will `Service2` be instantiated, and so on.

Or does all singleton service instantiate the first time a HTTP request is made, all scoped services instantiate every time a HTTP request is made, and all transient services instantiate even though they are not used during the HTTP request?

Comment: FWIW You can test this yourself. :)

Comment: The DI container is lazy. Each service will be created on first use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you injecting services. There are two popular approaches.

The first one is injecting in a controller constructor:

```cs
public class Controller1 : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IService1 _service1;
    private readonly IService2 _service2;

    public Controller1(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
    {
        this._service1 = service1;
        this._service2 = service2;
    }

    [HttpPost("request-1")]
    public IActionResult Request1()
    {
        // Do something with service1
    }

    [HttpPost("request-2")]
    public IActionResult Request2()
    {
        // Do something with service2
    }
}
```

In this case, all dependencies are instantiated due to fact that the controller is constructed, even though they may be not used during the HTTP request

The second approach is injecting in controller actions:

```cs
public class Controller1 : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("request-1")]
    public IActionResult Request1([FromServices] IService1 service1)
    {
        // Do something with service1
    }

    [HttpPost("request-2")]
    public IActionResult Request2([FromServices] IService2 service2)
    {
        // Do something with service2
    }
}
```

In this case action dependencies are instantiated only when the action is called.  But it doesn’t mean this approach is better. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656115) to learn more

Above I described general behavior for all injected services. If we dive into lifetime differences, we get this:

- All singleton services instantiate **only the first time** a HTTP request is made
- All scoped and transient services instantiate **every time** a HTTP
  request is made

  - Scope services instantiate only once for each HTTP request
  - Transient services can instantiate **multiple times** for one HTTP request. It happens when your controller injects few transient services, and implementations of these services have the same one dependency on other transient service. This internal service has unique instance for every usage