# Dependency injection unneeded services

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Imagine we are using some Dependency injection and we use it in some controllers.

For example Laravel or any other framework with DI (doesn't matter the language in this case PHP).

Let's say we have this controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(UserRepository $users, Mailer $mailer, Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->logger = $logger;       
    }
    public function method1(){...}
    public function method2(){...}
    public function index(UserRepository $users){...}
}
```

Everybody say this is good design, but my question is this:

If the controller calls ***method1*** and it uses only **mailer** for example, whats the point to construct the object with all the 3 dependencies. Isn't this not optimal even it doesn't take a lot of memory or performance ?

Somebody can think that this controller needs all of them but in reality if I call only ***method1*** it will need only **mailer**.

If I try to inject the dependencies on the methods like "index" method, how can I do it because If i extend the same method and need different dependencies PHP will blow up because the method signatures are not the same.

What is the best way to handle this.

If I extract each method in separate controllers I'll have to do a lot of repetitions.

Thanks

Comment: I mean both methods take $userId for example but in UserController I need Logger service, so I cannot add it as parameter in the method to be injected - it will need to be injected in the constructor, but that way this service maybe not needed in the other controller methods.

Comment: You either need to inject it in the constructor or create a new method for it. There isn't really any way around that afaik. If the method has different dependencies/signature than the parent, it should be it's own method either way.

Comment: "best way" by what objective metric(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to consider:

- First of all, when [injection constructors are simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), it shouldn't matter that not all dependencies are used all the time. This shouldn't cause any measurable performance penalty, because the performance bottleneck will typically be caused by I/O.
- If, however, your class contains many dependencies, and there are a lot of dependencies that are only used in some methods, it might be an indication that the methods on the class are not cohesive. That again could be an indication of the class violating the Single Responsibility Principle. In other words, the class might be too big, has multiple responsibilities, and if that's the case, it should be split into multiple smaller classes. Grouping class functionality around the concept of an entity (such as `UserController` does) is often a cause by SRP violations. Instead, a better solution typically is to group classes around functionality; e.g. `DeleteUserController`, `PromoteUserController`, `BlockUserController`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, one problem is with testing - i have to provide all the dependencies or 4 mock object just to test one method even it uses only 1 of the dependency. But maybe its not so big problem in the end.

Comment: There are patterns that can help you simplifying your tests. Take a look at this [sut factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595171/264697), for instance. But again, if the methods of your class not cohesive, it's an indication that the class violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Thanks, is it ok to make the parameters like this (logger = di('logger') - the di is global function that returns the logger object from the container or this is bad practice

Comment: That seems to be a variation of the Service Locator anti-pattern.